# find the correlation for a time series of hourly measurements

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have the following example:

```
DateTime=datestr(datenum('2011-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
    'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Data = [datenum(DateTime) - datenum(2011,0,0),rand(13,length(DateTime(:,1)))'];
```

This data contains the day of year in the first column, water temperature in column (2:end-1) and air temperature in the last column. I would like to calculate the correlation between air temperature (last column) and each column of temperature. I can do this as follows:

```
R = arrayfun(@(i)nonzeros(tril(corrcoef(Data(:,i),Data(:,end)),-1)),2:size(Data,2)-1,'un',0);
```

Next, I am trying to generate a matrix of the correlation values for each individual days (i.e. each 24 rows). So my question is how can I calculate the correlation between each column of temperature with air temperature as indicated above but for each individual day as denoted by 'Data(:,i)'. The outcome should include 365 rows (days) and 12 columns (temperatures)

In addition, I can find the row number for each day by:

```
[a,b,b] = unique(floor(Data(:,1)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dayIdx = floor(Data(:,1));
R = zeros(365,12);
for i=1:365
    c = corrcoef( Data(dayIdx==i,:) ); %# corr between all variables for one day
    R(i,:) = c(end,2:end-1);    %# extract those between water temps and air temp
end
```